# Filtering JSON data in a list

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath

I am new to working with JSON data. I am having difficulty on how to return back bicycles that have a color of "Blue". Using JSONPath.

The following example JSON file.

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
        "bicycle": [
            {
                "price": 19.95
                "color": [
                    "red"
                ],
            },
            {
                "price": 20.99
                "color": [
                    "blue",
                    "Green"
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to use the following filter but it doesn't work.

```
$.store.bicycle[?(@.color=='blue')]
```

Any ideas to how to get this to work and only return the price of bicycles that are Blue?

Any information is greatly welcomed.

Comment: Take a look at underscore.js - very useful when needing to filter/grab data from JSON. `var prices = _.filter(yourJSON.bicycle, function(bicycle) { return bicycle.color == 'blue' });`

Answer (score 0):

The JSON Data is

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            }],
        "bicycle": [
            {
                "price": 19.95,
                "color": [
                    "red"
                ]
            },
            {
                "price": 20.99,
                "color": [
                    "blue",
                    "Green"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The JSONPath is

```
$.store.bicycle[?(@.color.indexOf('blue') != -1)]
```

Comment: Thanks @Roger Ng tried this but not working. Am using https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ to test when testing I get a syntax error.

Comment: The syntax error comes from your JSON Data. I've edited my answer to include the corrected JSON Data.